# Android object collection having same value

Tags: android, json, iteration

I have Json object in format  { "result": { "name": "ram", "mark": "50" }, { "name": "ram", "mark": "60" }, { "name": "ram", "mark": "50" }, { "name": "ram", mark: "50" }, { "name": "ram", "mark": "50" }, { "name": "ram", "mark": "80" }, { "name": "ram", "mark": "50" } } . How to collect same set of object having same marks in one list and other object having different marks in different list.please help..thanks in advance.

Comment: First, what have you tried? Post the relevant code along with any errors you are facing. Second, is this a valid JSON at all? The _mark_ tags are not enclosed in double quotes (should be `"mark"`).

Answer (score 1):

Thats not the valid json data,you can validate it here by putting your json data.
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

Your json data should be like:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "name": "ram",
        "mark": "50"
    },
    {
        "name": "raj",
        "mark": "60"
    },
    {
        "name": "ramesh",
        "mark": "70"
    },
    {
        "name": "manish",
        "mark": "50"
    },
    {
        "name": "priya",
        "mark": "50"
    },
    {
        "name": "shiv",
        "mark": "80"
    },
    {
        "name": "pankaj",
        "mark": "50"
    }]
}
```

And code for this is:

```
List list = new ArrayList<String>();
JSON Object json = new JSONObject();
if(json.has("result")){
   JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("result");
   if(array.length() > 0){
     for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
     JSONObject result = array.getJSONObject(i);
     list.add(result.getString("mark"));
  }
 }
}
```